# Pandas Pivot repeat index row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

If I export a Pandas Pivot Table to CSV table I get

```
first  second   
bar    one     A    0.721555
               B   -0.706771
       two     A   -1.039575
               B    0.271860
baz    one     A   -0.424972
               B    0.567020
       two     A    0.276232
               B   -1.087401
```

because I am working with this data in excel, I would have all rows repeated, for example

```
first  second   
bar    one     A    0.721555
bar    one     B   -0.706771
bar    two     A   -1.039575
bar    two     B    0.271860
baz    one     A   -0.424972
baz    one     B    0.567020
baz    two     A    0.276232
baz    two     B   -1.087401
```

Do you know how is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can create columns from `MultiIndex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then not write default index by parameter `index=False`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```